# Shortcut to pop out Microsoft Teams app in new window

Tags: microsoft-teams

Microsoft Teams allows you to "pop out app" for most apps into a new window.

Is there a way to script as a desktop shortcut, so it works like a progressive web app?

Comment: What do you need in addition to the "Pop out" button?

Comment: I want to create a shortcut, so I can click it and it opens the app, rather than having to open teams first and go via there

Comment: See if [this](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) helps, for URL such as `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/APP_ID?card=<TaskInfo.card>&height=<TaskInfo.height>&width=<TaskInfo.width>&title=<TaskInfo.title>&completionBotId=BOT_APP_ID`.